# What does 'RTTI symbol not found for class' warning mean?

Tags: android, c++, gcc, boost

I am making native application for android. It's written in C++, compiled using GCC 4.9 and using Boost 1.59 and Qt libraries. I see these pink warnings in the QtCreator console:

```
RTTI symbol not found for class 'boost::signals2::signal<void (), boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>, int, std::less<int>, boost::function<void ()>, boost::function<void (boost::signals2::connection const&)>, boost::signals2::mutex>'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'boost::signals2::signal<void (), boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>, int, std::less<int>, boost::function<void ()>, boost::function<void (boost::signals2::connection const&)>, boost::signals2::mutex>'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'boost::signals2::signal<void (), boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>, int, std::less<int>, boost::function<void ()>, boost::function<void (boost::signals2::connection const&)>, boost::signals2::mutex>'
```

The application is running on Android phone.

This is disturbing because I also have segfault crashes coming from `signals2` library. What does that warning exactly mean and where does it come from?

Comment: It means you didn't build your application with RTTI support. Should be a flag to compiler. Most likely, your toolchain emited -fno-rtti to gcc, since RTTI is enabled in gcc by default.

Comment: @SergeyA Whoa, lot's of things for me to google. I have no idea what you're talking about right now.

Comment: GCC 4.9 is *ancient*. You should seriously consider upgrading your compiler.

Comment: @JesperJuhl This question is also ancient, so maybe that might explain the old compiler?

Answer (score 1):

The error may be caused by bugs in GDB, which are excited by GCC behaviour.

https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-help/2017-08/msg00120.html

The GCC development team's latest prognosis is given by Paul Smith at the GCC Bugzilla issue tracker:

> It's apparently the tip of a particularly gross iceberg.  It doesn't
> seem like partial measures appeal to people, and no one has the needed
> combination of time, knowledge, and contacts to attack the entire
> iceberg.